# How can I formally prove this obvious surjection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Note: I will be using **$\uplus$ to represent disjoint unions**. $f$ and $g$ are not explicitly defined in the question I have and are meant to be abstract.

I have some 2 surjections $C : A \mapsto B$ and $D : X \mapsto Y$, and I want to show that:

a) $f : A\times X \mapsto B \times Y$ is a surjective function too, and

b) $g : A \uplus X \mapsto B \uplus Y$ is also surjective.

I know it's kind of obvious that since A and B are domains of surjective functions, we can definitely map all values in the domains to a corresponding value in its co-domain. Formally, we want to show that $\forall a \in A$, there exists some $b \in B$ such that $f(a) = b$. Since function $C$ can at least map to one element in $B$, and so could D for mapping X to Y, part (a) seems obvious.

But is there a way to prove this formally? I have meddled with some set builder notation but it looks unclean and all it seems is that I'm writing unnecessary notations.

Also for proving the disjoint union function is surjective, I have tried letting $\forall (k, n), n \in \{0, 1\}, k\in A \lor k \in X$, we have some $l \in B \lor l \in Y$ such that $g(k,n) = (l, n)$.

But this doesn't seem to be the right way to prove it.

Comment: I don't understand how $f$ or $g$ are defined.  For example, what is $f(a,x)$?  Is it $(C(a), D(x))$?

Comment: I'm afraid you're confusing the notion of everywhere defined function and that of surjective map. The hypotheses are that $C$  has domain (r=the whole of $A$ and that every $b\in B$ has a pre-image in $A$. Similarly for $C$.

Comment: Other  question: in the second question, does your notation denote  the disjoint sum?

Comment: @Bernard As per the first sentence, it denotes the disjoint union, yes?

Comment: Do you mean the first question? It's the product of the sets.

Comment: @Bernard Are you responding to me?  In the very first sentence of the question, it is stated that $\uplus$ denotes the disjoint union.  Hence in the second question, the notation indicates the disjoint union.  I'm not sure what the confusion is...

Comment: Sorry. It seems I overlooked this  first line.

Comment: @XanderHenderson $f(a,x)$ simply means a function that takes in all $a$ from $A$ and all $x$ from $X$ to produce some element in $B$ and $Y$ respectively. So you are right.

Comment: Also, I don't get why you say that $f$ and $g$ have to be defined, because the goal is to just arbitrary map some domain to a codomain, so the actual function written probably doesn't matter. I hope you don't blame me for writing the question this way.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959 I'm sorry... what?  Are you just trying to show that if there exist surjective maps $A\to B$ and $X\to Y$, then there exists a surjective map $A\times B \to X \times Y$?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes this is the goal. It might seem obvious, but is there a formal way to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's  start with the first problem -- saying what $f$ and $g$ are:

I believe you mean to write
$$
f: A \times X \to B \times Y : (a, x) \mapsto (C(a), D(x))
$$
and for the second, I think you mean that 
$$
g: A \cup X \to B \cup Y : u \mapsto \begin{cases} 
C(u) & u \in A\\
D(u) & u \in X
\end{cases}.
$$
Do I have that about right? If not, please correct me. But without *some* definition of $f$ and $g$, the whole problem is meaningless.

Assuming so, let's proceed to the second problem, which is considerably easier once that first (unwritten) one is out of the way.

To show that $f$ is surjective, take an arbitrary element $(b, y)$ of the codomain, where 
$b \in B$ and $y \in Y$. Because $f$ is surjective, there's some element 
$q \in A$ with $C(q) = b$; similarly, there's an element $r \in X$ with $D(r) = y$ (again by surjectivity).

Now look at $f(q, r)$. By definition (which you have to write down or the whole problem is meaningless!), we have

$$
f(q, r) = (C(q), D(r)) = (b, y).
$$
Hence the point $(b, y)$ is in the image of $f$.

Now: you try it for the disjoint union case. Your proof will have two cases, depending on whether the target item $s$ is in $B$ or is in $Y$. It cannot be in both, because the codomain is a disjoint union (even though I haven't used the special symbol for that).

Answer (score 2):

First off, based on your comments, I believe that *statements* of the things that you want to prove are something like this:

> Suppose that $A$, $B$, $X$, and $Y$.  Further assume that there exist surjective functions
>   $$ f: A\to B \qquad\text{and}\qquad g : X\to Y. $$
>   Then there exist surjective maps $A\times X \to B\times Y$, and $A\sqcup X \to B\sqcup Y$ (where $\sqcup$ denotes the disjoint union).

For the first statement, define a map $h : A\times X \to B\times Y$ by
$$ h(a,x) = (f(a),g(x)). $$
We claim that $h$ is surjective.  Let $(b,y) \in B\times Y$—our goal is to find some point $(b',y') \in A\times X$ such that $h(b',y') = (b,y)$.  Since $f$ is surjective, there is some point $b' \in A$ such that $f(b') = b$.  Since $g$ is surjective, there is some point $y' \in X$ such that $g(y') = y$.  Then, by definition of $h$, we have
$$ h(b',y') = (f(b'), g(y')) = (b,y).$$
Therefore $h$ is surjective.

For the second statement, let's first be very careful about the definition of the disjoint union.  This is usually defined by
$$ A \sqcup B := (A\times \{0\}) \cup (B\times \{1\}).$$
The reason to do this is that $A$ and $B$ might be subsets of some larger set, but the disjoint union somehow remembers the original set membership of its elements.  As a basic example, $[0,1] \cup [0,1] = [0,1]$,
while $[0,1]\sqcup[0,1]$ consists of two copies of the interval that are "placed next to each other."

With this in mind, define a map $k : A\sqcup X \to B\sqcup Y$ by
$$ k(s,i) = \begin{cases}
(f(s),0) & \text{if $i=0$, and} \\
(g(s),1) & \text{if $i=1$.}
\end{cases} $$
Basically, $i$ keeps track of which set the point $s$ originally belonged to.  Hence $k$ looks at $i$, determines which set $s$ belongs to, then applies the appropriate map to that point, retaining the appropriate group membership.  The claim is that $k$ is surjective.

Suppose that $(t,j) \in B\sqcup Y$.  There are two cases:  either (1) $j=0$ or (2) $j=1$.

1. If $j=0$, then $t \in B$.  By the surjectivity of $f$, there is a point $t'\in A$ such that $f(t') = t$.  It therefore follows that $$k(t',0) = (f(t'),0) = (t,0). $$
   Hence we have found a point $(s,i) = (t',0) \in A\sqcup X$ that is sent to $(t,j)$ by $k$.
2. If $j=1$, then $t \in Y$.  By the surjectivity of $g$, there is a point $t'\in X$ such that $g(t') = t$.  It therefore follows that $$k(t',1) = (g(t'),1) = (t,1). $$
   Hence we have found a point $(s,i) = (t',1) \in A\sqcup X$ that is sent to $(t,j)$ by $k$.

In either case, given an arbitrary $(t,j) \in B\sqcup Y$, we can find a point $(s,i)$ such that $k(s,i) = (t,j)$.  Therefore $k$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

I'll sketch the second question. We define $g $ as $$g(x)=\begin{cases}C(x)&\text{if }x\in A \\ D(x)&\text{if }x\in X \end{cases}.$$
Now consider an element $t\in B\uplus Y$. Then

- either $t\in B$. In this case, by hypothesis, $t=C(a)$ for some $a\in A$. But $a$ also lies  in $A\uplus X$, and then $C(a)=g(a)$.
- or $t\in Y$. I think you can proceed.

Comment: Do you mean that $t \in B$?

Comment: Oh! yes. Lapsus calami. For my excuse, it's getting late here…